# Extract value from XML from String

Tags: java

I did some codes but they are not working. **I also need to validate if a header:message exists**

```
String xml = "<header:HostError>
<header:message>
    <header:messageCode>321</header:messageCode>
    <header:message>test</header:message>
</header:message>
<header:message>
    <header:messageCode>123</header:messageCode>
    <header:message>test</header:message>
</header:message>
</header:HostError>"
```

How do I get the first messageCode and message?

```
    private void extractErrorsFromResponse(SOAPFaultDetail faultResponse) {

    for (Iterator itr = faultResponse.getAllDetailEntries(); itr.hasNext(); ) {
        Object element = itr.next();
        if (element instanceof OMElement) {             
            Object code = ((OMElement) element).getFirstChildWithName(new QName("message")).getFirstChildWithName(new QName("messageCode"));
            Object message = ((OMElement) element).getFirstChildWithName(new QName("message")).getFirstChildWithName(new QName("message"));
            faultResponse.addDetailEntry(((OMElement) element).cloneOMElement());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this just plain XML or related to SOAP?

Comment: Take a look on [`JAXB`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/index.html) and [`Jackson`](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-xml-serialization-and-deserialization)

Comment: It's a String. I just want to extract the first 2 values.

Comment: you can always try a regexp...

Comment: it can either be String or `SOAPFaultDetail`

Comment: "I did some codes but they are not working" - Show us your code, explain in detail what you mean by "not working", then we can help you find out what's wrong with your code.

Comment: I will post my current code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick solution would be that.

```
String xml = "<header:HostError>" +
     "<header:message>\n" +
     "<header:messageCode>321</header:messageCode>\n" +
     "<header:message>test</header:message>\n" +
     "</header:message>\n" +
     "<header:message>\n" +
     "<header:messageCode>123</header:messageCode>\n" +
     "<header:message>test</header:message>\n" +
     "</header:message>\n" +
     "</header:HostError>";

DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));

NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("header:messageCode");

System.out.println("First messageCode : " + list.item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());

NodeList list_ = doc.getElementsByTagName("header:message");
System.out.println("First message : " + list_.item(1).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
```

It prints,

```
First messageCode : 321
First message : test
```

Based on that, you need to find a more generic method.

Comment: why parse the document twice?

Comment: Sure, there is no need to parse it twice, my mistake. Thanks on noticing! I'll edit my response accordingly ;)